# Configure CMakeLists.txt for locally installed Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, ros

I downloaded the Protocol Buffers source from [GitHub](https://github.com/google/protobuf/). I don't want to install it globally and just want to use it in my ROS package. I found `cmake` files [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake) but not sure how to use them in my project.

Below is the content of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(local_protobuf_ros_example)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(addressbook_protobuf include/addressbook.pb.cc)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} addressbook_protobuf ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Below is the file structure of ROS Package:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── addressbook.pb.cc
│   ├── addressbook.pb.h
│   └── addressbook.proto
├── lib
│   ├── protobuf-3.5.0
│   │   ├── cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │   ├── examples.cmake
│   │   │   ├── extract_includes.bat.in
│   │   │   ├── install.cmake
│   │   │   ├── libprotobuf.cmake
│   │   │   ├── libprotobuf-lite.cmake
│   │   │   ├── libprotoc.cmake
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-config.cmake.in
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-config-version.cmake.in
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-lite.pc.cmake
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-module.cmake.in
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-options.cmake
│   │   │   ├── protobuf.pc.cmake
│   │   │   ├── protoc.cmake
│   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   └── tests.cmake
│   │   ├──SOME_FILES_ARE_NOT_BEING_SHOWN_HERE
│   └── protobuf-cpp-3.5.0.zip
├── package.xml
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

**I want to know that how to configure above `CMakeLists.txt` so that it uses locally installed Protocol Buffers?**

Comment: What is not working, `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` returns error? Look at the [set of possible installation prefixes for the package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html)

Comment: @Ptaq666: It seems that `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` is pointing to system default protocol buffers, which is an old version. I have the new version but I don't know how to configure `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` to point to this version.

Comment: In `find_package` you can also specify the version of the package - along with @piwi answer this should resolve the problem.

Comment: @Ptaq666: That's a great suggestion. However, can I point `find_package` to a directory, containing `protobuf`? To be precise, `protobuf-3.5.0` is kept inside `lib` subdirectory of the ROS package. Also, `cmake` files provided by `protobuf` are kept in `lib/protobuf-3.5.0/cmake` subdirectory.

Comment: You have to point find_package() to `lib/protobuf-3.5.0/cmake` so it can find the appropriate CMake configuration script; however, there is a `protobuf-config.cmake.in` file, not `protobuf-config.cmake`, which means a `configure_file()` is needed at some point. You will have to check the documentation of Protobuf or ROS to find out how to properly setup your local install.

Comment: @piwi: Some instructions are given [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md) but I am not sure which one is applicable in this scenario. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can set [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) when you configure your build directory to specify a custom location to search for packages. You are not required to modify your `CMakeLists.txt`, configure your build for example like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/protobuf/cmake/config /path/to/source
```

Comment: Since I am using ROS, I need to use `catkin_make` command. The `cmake` files of Protocol Buffers are kept [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake). Can you tell me how to modify `CMakeLists.txt` to use the Protocol Buffers kept inside `lib` directory?